# Amadeus has an api to return flights and connections

Tags: amadeus

In amadeus standalone its possible to return the fligts and the connections and also the bagage and the connections for them, but i want to know if the api has some method that return that kind of data.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the Amadeus Self-Service APIs you can find the following APIs:

- [Flight Offers Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search) to search for flight offers and their connections, you can also find information for bags.
- [Flight Offers Price](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price) confirms the availability and final price of flights returned by the Flight Offers Search API. The API also provides pricing for ancillary products like additional bags.